# Unable to set a variable in UITableViewCell from parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView and a custom TableViewCell class, I am setting a non-null value in viewDidLoad method, but while setting the value to UITableViewCell in cellForRow method , the value magically becomes nil. I am unable to access the set variable from my custom UITableViewCell
Here is the snippet of code. Print statement in ViewDidLoad prints the value while the one in cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Docco360Util.shared().getDoctorsWithResultBlock { (doctorObjects, error) in
        if let err = error{
            print(err)
        }else{
            self.doctors=doctorObjects
            print(doctorObjects![1].professionalHeader)//output is printed here
            self.doctorTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifierForUsers = "DoctorTableViewCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifierForUsers, for: indexPath) as! DoctorTableViewCell
    if cell == nil{
        cell=DoctorTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: identifierForUsers)
    }
    print(self.doctors[indexPath.row].professionalHeader)//output in nil here
    cell.doctor=self.doctors[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Which value becomes `nil`, is it `doctors`? Btw the `if cell == nil` line can never be called (and the compiler should give you a warning for this)`, since due to the forced casting `cell` can never be optional, you'll receive a runtime error if the casting would fail (though it cannot fail if you set up the cell reuse identifier and cell class correctly.

Comment: have you write self.doctorTableView.delegate = self, self.doctorTableView.dataSource = self ?

Comment: cell is not nil, init method in cell is being called. Cells are visible but with no labels set in them.
Yes, datasource and delegate are set.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DoctorTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DoctorTableViewCell

    print(self.doctors[indexPath.row].professionalHeader)
    cell.doctor = self.doctors[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Tried, but still, value is non nil in viewDidLoad but nil in cellForRow

Comment: Check, if `self.doctors=doctorObjects`

            `print(self.doctors[1].professionalHeader)`
Is printing the value or not ..

Comment: Yes, value is correctly printed here `self.doctors=doctorObjects print(self.doctors[1].professionalHeader)`

Comment: Then Do `cell.doctor=self.doctors[indexPath.row].professionalHeader`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should ensure that the closure of `Docco360Util.shared().getDoctorsWithResultBlock` is executed in the main (UI) thread. If not, you should put it into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

Then, you should verify that the result block is executed (e.g. the print statement prints something). Btw, why do you call `print(doctorObjects![1].professionalHeader)` with index `1` and not `0`? In `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt:)` you element with index `0` - maybe this `doctor` is `nil`?

You could start by setting a breakpoint to your property declaration, a watchpoint, or implement a property observer (`willSet`) and add a breakpoint her, to check if somebody is messing up with your variables.

If all this does not help, you might want to post more code, expecially all lines of code where you write your `self.doctors` array.

Comment: I knew doctorObjects will return 3 objects,  `doctorObjects![1].professionalHeader` was used just to print the output at various places.
I was able to print the output in ViewDidLoad but not in UITableViewCell

Comment: I am reloading tableView in the success block. So I guess it is not a threading issue

Comment: I don't know what `Docco360Util` is, so it's hard to say whether or not the block is executed in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally fix it. The problem was in declaration of variables. I was using Objective-C header file for declarations. While declaring I declared them as "weak" instead of "retain" and that was causing the problem.